# angular jasmine 2 vs 1.3.1 unit tests

Tags: jasmine

This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eqiGbvh7chSrRj3wMiRm?p=preview) shows the test working with Jasmine 1.3.1, but the same code fails using Jasmine 2.  I get an error about the spec being undefined, and referencing angular-mocks.js (line 1674).  Commenting out the code in SpecRunner.html will toggle the two versions.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the syntax has been changed in Jasmine version 2.0.0.

To understand basic things about the Jasmine.js v2.0 you can read it from: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

This helps bit more.

Comment: It would be much better to answer the specific question of this user instead of just pointing them to a generic introduction article about the differences between Jasmine 1 and 2.